# Dynamic Table Name and Paramers in SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

```
create procedure dbo.move_pos
(
@id int,
@tbl varchar(50)
)    
as    
begin    
declare @pos int    
exec('select '+@pos+'=POS from '+@tbl+' where id='+@id)    
exec('update '+@tbl+'  set POS=POS+1 where POS<'+@pos)    
end
```

In above procedure column POS is of type int. But when I m executing this procedure it is showing following error :

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>
> Incorrect syntax near '='.

I m using SQL SERVER 2012. Need help. Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: select '+@pos+'=POS from '+@tbl+' where id='+@id wht u want to do with @pos

Comment: try this 
declare query varchar(100);
set query='select '+cast(pos as varchar)+' from '+tbl+' where id='+CAST(id AS varchar)
exec (query)
add @before query,id,pos

Comment: @YashveerSingh I m trying to move a item on top so I m using pos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend rethinking all this dynamic sql stored procedures.
However, if you really must use dynamic sql, try this instead:

```
create procedure dbo.move_pos
(
    @id int,
    @tbl varchar(50)
)    
as    
begin    
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
set @sql = 'update ' + QUOTENAME(@tbl) + '
            set POS = POS + 1 
            where POS < (
                select POS 
                from ' + QUOTENAME(@tbl) + ' 
                where id = '+ cast(@id as nvarchar(10)
            )'

exec(@sql)    
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Zohar It is working fine. Thankyou very much.